# There is a syntax error in the following SQL code. Why?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```
"SELECT tblStudent.StudentName, tblStudent.Username FROM tblStudent " & _
"INNER JOIN tblClasses/Students ON tblStudent.StudentID = tblClasses/Students.StudentID " & _
"INNER JOIN tblClasses ON tblClasses/Students.ClassID = tblClasses.ClassID " & _
"WHERE tblClasses.ClassName = '" & lstClasses.SelectedItem & "';"
```

Here, lstClasses.SelectedItem refers to the name of the class in tblClasses. I have already tested to see if this is the issue but the 'SelectedItem' is what I had hoped, so this cannot be it.

Comment: I've never seen / in table name before, is this what you want? Have you tried running the query directly in access?

Comment: For one thing, object names have punctuation/special characters. Enclose in [ ]. `[tblClasses/Students]`. Advise not to use punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention. Use Access query builder to get correct syntax. Might need parens around JOIN clause.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  It would solve your problem, too. If SelectedItem is a class, you would have to cast it to that class and specify the property for ClassName.

Comment: When you say *there is a syntax error*, include the exact error message that you're seeing. It's on the screen right in front of you, but we can't see your screen from where we're sitting. The words in error messages are meaningful.

Comment: @LarsTech: Not sure parameters would solve the issue of `tblClasses/Students`. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the string like this:

```vb
Dim sql As String = _
    "SELECT tblStudent.StudentName, tblStudent.Username" & _
    " FROM tblStudent s" & _
    " INNER JOIN [tblClasses/Students] cs ON s.StudentID = cs.StudentID" & _
    " INNER JOIN tblClasses c ON cs.ClassID = c.ClassID" & _
    " WHERE c.ClassName = ? ;"
```

Notice the square brackets (`[]`) around the odd table name (and using aliases to avoid needing to repeat it). Also note how the SQL string uses a placeholder for the selected class name. Later on, include the selected class like this:

```vb
'Use the actual type and length of the database column here
sqlCommandObject.Parameters.Add("@ClassName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = lstClasses.SelectedItem
```

This can help things run faster, and also fixes a **HUGE** security hole in how the original code was written. Finally, it makes it possible to use characters like `'` as part of the classname without needing any other special handling.

Comment: Just noticed the Q is tagged for Access; updated to use OleDb rather than Sql Server ADO.Net objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MS Access with multiple joins, each join will need to be enclosed within a set of parentheses, e.g.:

```
Dim strSQL AS String
strSQL = strSQL & "select "
strSQL = strSQL & "    t.studentname, "
strSQL = strSQL & "    t.username "
strSQL = strSQL & "from "
strSQL = strSQL & "    ( "
strSQL = strSQL & "        tblstudent t1 inner join [tblclasses/students] t2 on "
strSQL = strSQL & "        t1.studentid = t2.studentid "
strSQL = strSQL & "    ) "
strSQL = strSQL & "    inner join tblclasses t3 on "
strSQL = strSQL & "    t2.classid = t3.classid "
strSQL = strSQL & "where "
strSQL = strSQL & "    t3.classname = @class "
```

Comment: If you need to build a string use a StringBuilder. You are creating a whole bunch of strings.